# How Would You Draw a RectangleF with Spritebatch.Draw?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, system.drawing, spritebatch

I'm trying to create a top down game where you can move in 8 directions. I've implemented Vector2 in order to move in a normalised manner. I use a spritebatch system to draw with standard rectangles (source and destination) but soon changed to RectangleF as regular rectangles use integers.

The Spritebatch does not recognise the RectangleF and hence returns the error, "Cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.RectangleF' to 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2'?". The Color also returns ambiguous and no matter 'System.Drawing' or 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color', it always returns how it cannot be converted into 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle'.

In this code, a Vector2 (Position) is called in and used to draw the RectangleF's position. I then use the Spritebatch.Draw to draw a texture with the Source and Destination and it is always updated to give the implication of a moving character.

```
public static RectangleF destinationRectangle, sourceRectangle;

public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)   
    {
        int width = 64;
        int height = 64;
        realPositionX = PlayerMovement.Position.X; 
        realPositionY = PlayerMovement.Position.Y;

        sourceRectangle = new RectangleF(currentFrame * width, row * height, width, height);
        destinationRectangle = new RectangleF(realPositionX, realPositionY, width, height);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(Player, destinationRectangle, sourceRectangle, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.White); //Error Occurs Here
        spriteBatch.End();
    }
```

I'm confused as how I should approach this issue, is there a way of drawing a RectangleF through SpriteBatch or do I have to look at another method?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot use a `RectangleF` with Spritebatch. I've had success writing my own `RectangleF` structure that includes an explicit conversion to MonoGame's `Rectangle`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, maybe I need to look into alternative methods as to how my character is drawn and updated.

Comment: Just change the usage of rectangleF to rectangle? Especially since it's created at every draw call, you won't experience performance loss.

Anyway, there is a reason why you want integer when drawing sprites. You always want to be "pixel perfect", otherwise you end up with some drawing artifacts.

Also, I don't see why they need to be static, this is usually not a good idea.

Comment: @HeX I had another look at your code. If you're looking to draw only the character's position at float values, there's a `Draw` overload that takes in a `Vector2`, which you can create using the RectangleF's X and Y values.

Comment: Thank you both for replying. I have since changed it back to using regular rectangle. I also realised that there are specific numbers you can use that can counteract this problem. What started this all was that the player's position behaves badly if non normalised. If you do happen to normalise, your values will be given in floats and hence it defeats the purpose if rectangles use integers. Say the number 7, if you normalise it you get (7 x 0.707 = 4.949), round this value (5) and when the code runs, it uses integers again. (sqrt(5^2 + 5^2) = 7.07), ~ 7 (starting number). Good enough :)

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no reason to use RectangleF.
Usually you use a pixel based coordinate system in your game and therefore the Rectangle Class is what you want to go for.

Other than that it is a better approach to store the players postion in a Vector2 and using the the appropriate overload:

```
SpriteBatch.Draw (Texture2D, Vector2, Color)
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't have many resources online about how animating works but now I know. I also did read someone above say that rectangleF is not good for pixel perfect movement. Above I wrote a detailed solution to what I ended up using. But yeah, thanks for letting me know and confirming the above :D

Comment: In this case I highly recommend this tutorial http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/monogame-2d-tutorials